# Sharp inequality $\pi^{-e}-e^{-\pi}> \frac{e^{\frac{1}{e}-e-\pi}}{\pi}$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, pi

I have some interest for the following inequality :

> > $$\pi ^{-e}-e^{-\pi}> \frac{e^{\frac{1}{e}-e-\pi}}{\pi}$$

I have tried to study the following function :
$$f(x)=x^{-y}-y^{-x}$$
And after use convexity but it's really too sharp to this kind of reasoning .

So I have used power series to get  big polynomials .Unfortunatly  I can't solve this way.

Furthermore the inequality :

> > Let $x>y>0$ then we have :
> >     $$x ^{-y}-y^{-x}> \frac{y^{\frac{1}{y}-y-x}}{x}$$

is false.

My question :How to solve it ?

So if you have great ideas...

...Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Oh,How to prove it ?

Comment: You should know that in English, *no* space goes *before* a period, comma, colon, semicolon or question mark, and a space *must* go *after* these punctuation marks. See how I’ve demonstrated that?